# Elegant way of safely changing the day of ruby Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have to create a list of 24 months with the same `day` amongst them, properly handling the months that do not have day 29, 30 or 31.

What I currently do is:

```
def dates_list(first_month, assigned_day)
 (0...24).map do |period|
    begin
      (first_month + period.months).change(day: assigned_day)
    rescue ArgumentError
      (first_month + period.months).end_of_month
    end
  end
end
```

I need to rescue from `ArgumentError` as some cases raise it:

```
Date.parse('10-Feb-2019').change(day: 30)
# => ArgumentError: invalid date
```

I am looking for a *safe* and *elegant* solution that might already exist in ruby or rails. Something like:

```
Date.parse('10-Feb-2019').safe_change(day: 30) # => 28-Feb-2019
```

So I can write:

```
def dates_list(first_month, assigned_day)
  (0...24).map do |period|
    (first_month + period.months).safe_change(day: assigned_day)
  end
end
```

Does that exist or I would need to monkey patch `Date`?

Workarounds (like a method that already creates this list) are very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***UPDATE***

The discussion about what to do with negative and 0 days made me realize this function is trying to guess the user's intent. And it also hard codes how many months to generate, and to generate by month.

This got me thinking what is this method doing? It's generates a list of advancing months, of a fixed size, and modifying them in a fixed way, and guessing what the user wants. If your function description includes "*and*" you probably need multiple functions. We separate generating the list of dates from modifying the list. We replace the hard coded parts with parameters. And instead of guessing what the user wants, we let them tell us with a block.

```
def date_generator(from, by:, how_many:)
  (0...how_many).map do |period|
    date = from + period.send(by)
    yield date
  end
end
```

The user can be very explicit about what they want to change. No surprises for the user nor the reader.

```
p date_generator(Date.parse('2019-02-01'), by: :month, how_many: 24) { |month|
  month.change(day: month.end_of_month.day)
}
```

We can take this a step further by turning it into an [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html). Then you can have as many as you like and do whatever you like with them using normal [Enumerable methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html)..

```
INFINITY = 1.0/0.0
def date_iterator(from, by:)
  Enumerator.new do |block|
    (0..INFINITY).each do |period|
      date = from + period.send(by)
      block << date
    end
  end
end

p date_iterator(Date.parse('2019-02-01'), by: :month)
    .take(24).map { |date|
      date.change(day: date.end_of_month.day)
    }
```

Now you can generate any list of dates, iterating by any field, of any length, with any changes. Rather than being hidden in a method, what's happening is very explicit to the reader. And if you have a special, common case you an wrap this in a method.

And the final step would be to make it a `Date` method.

```
class Date
  INFINITY = 1.0/0.0
  def iterator(by:)
    Enumerator.new do |block|
      (0..INFINITY).each do |period|
        date = self + period.send(by)
        block << date
      end
    end
  end
end

Date.parse('2019-02-01')
  .iterator(by: :month)
  .take(24).map { |date|
    date.change(day: date.end_of_month.day)
  }
```

And if you have a special, common case, you can write a special case function for it, give it a descriptive name, and document its special behaviors.

```
def next_two_years_of_months(date, day:)
  if day <= 0
    raise ArgumentError, "The day must be positive"
  end

  date.iterator(by: :month)
    .take(24)
    .map { |next_date|
      next_date.change(day: [day, next_date.end_of_month.day].min)
    }
end
```

---

***PREVIOUS ANSWER***

My first refactoring would be to remove the redundant code.

```
require 'date'

def dates_list(first_month, assigned_day)
 (0...24).map do |period|
   next_month = first_month + period.months
   begin
     next_month.change(day: assigned_day)
   rescue ArgumentError
     next_month.end_of_month
   end
 end
end
```

At this point, imo, the function is fine. It's clear what's happening. But you can take it a step further.

```
def dates_list(first_month, assigned_day)
  (0...24).map do |period|
    next_month = first_month + period.months
    day = [assigned_day, next_month.end_of_month.day].min
    next_month.change(day: day)
  end
end
```

I think that's marginally better. It makes the decision a little more explicit and doesn't paper over other possible argument errors.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you could add it as a `Date` method.

```
class Date
  def change_day(day)
    change(day: [day, end_of_month.day].min)
  end
end
```

I'm not so hot on either `change_day` nor `safe_change`. Neither really says "this will use the day or if it's out of bounds the last day of the month" and I'm not sure how to express that.

Comment: I find your second proposal to better aproach what I was looking for, it doesn't need to catch any error and still solves the problem.  Great answer.

Comment: @byrdEmmanuel Thanks! Since we're checking the day bound, negative and zero days are something you should consider. Negative days work as expected if you think about it a little bit, you get the last days of the previous month. Zero throws an ArgumentError from inside Date. Might be better to catch it early.

Comment: Just for completeness, probably the best way to prevent `day` from being 0 or a negative number is: `day = [[day, 1].max, next_month.end_of_month.day].min`

Comment: @byrdEmmanuel Because months have a varying number of days there's a valid reason to give a day which is too large (though not larger than 31). But there's no reason to give 0. And if negative days are not allowed there's no reason to give a negative day. `[day, 1].max` papers over a user error, is a silent surprising behavior, and will hide bugs. Instead of guessing the user's intent, throw an `ArgumentError` so they can decide if it's a bug or not.

Comment: @byrdEmmanuel All this guessing of the user's intent got me thinking. I've edited the answer with a much better solution.

Comment: @byrdEmmanuel I'm about to use this `Date#iterator` in my own code! I need to build statistics at the beginning of every hour, day, week, and so on. `from.beginning_of_hour.iterator(by: :hour).take_while { |hour| hour < Time.current.beginning_of_hour }.each { |hour| Stats.build_hour(hour) }`